# best way to creating card game on Android

Tags: android, card-game

I have a new idea for creating a new Uno like card game. I have Java programming experience but not in Android.

What is the best way creating card game on Android ? I mean handling cards easily as graphics objects.

Thanks advance for your answers.

Csaba

Comment: I have no Android experience as I state above, I have a good idea, I just need to know what libraries are the best way to starting the development.

Comment: My question is about game development, since I have no experience, this answer was helpful for me.

Comment: Sorry Byte56 because I did not try all the possibilities to find the best way to implement my idea. Sorry because I did not want waste weeks, sorry for taking advice another person who has more experience in android development. Sorry, because this is not a forum for get advice, and sorry for game related question.

Comment: From my perspective this is not a question suited for this site.  You are asking "what is the best way to create a card game". This is subjective and can't be answered properly.   I asked you what you tried and clearly you tried nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1, Libgdx

It's Java, and Google's ingress use this game engine.

2, cocos2d-x

Very good for 2d game, but coding language is c++ or Lua.

3, Unity3D

Good for 3d, and language is C#.